# Create a process that execute powershell in C# but failed outpt

Tags: c#, powershell, process

I dont know where is my missing. Even it dit not write out log. Could you fix my test code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"/C Import-Module AppLocker;Set-AppLockerPolicy -XMLPolicy 'iPolicy.xml' > C:\log.txt";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            //startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            //startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.Print("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is OK, I believe. Does the command "mport-Module AppLocker;Set-AppLockerPolicy -XMLPolicy 'iPolicy.xml' > C:\log.txt" run in powershell? Is the file "iPolicy.xml" accessible? Should you use full path?

Comment: Can you uncomment these lines:

   //startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    //startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
And show us the result from:

    process.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

Comment: The file iPolicy.xml is all accessible and the D partition have full permission

Comment: @iiliev I can't see any error (some red line) on the console. And the log file is not created.

Comment: @Honzajscz the command "Import-Module AppLocker;Set-AppLockerPolicy -XMLPolicy 'iPolicy.xml' > C:\log.txt" run in powershell. iPolicy.xml in same currunt path

Comment: Try to replace the argument with "PWD > current_dir.txt" to make sure that the folder is really where you expect

Comment: @Honzajscz It created a file current_dir.txt in same program file.

Comment: and what is in the current_dir.txt?

Comment: Path                                                                           
----                                                                           
C:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\process\process...

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work, code should look like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C powershell.exe /C Import-Module AppLocker;Set-AppLockerPolicy -XMLPolicy 'iPolicy.xml' > C:\log.txt";
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

This worked for me! You can use full paths to `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe` if you feel necessary, it's not that important here.

Comment: Very thank @Emons. I always play ps script on console and it's ok. Even I checked policies in Local Security Policy and in the log file. But now I convert into C# code and I am facing this problem. I wonder about the using ofmulti-command in the parametter of startInfo

Comment: Wow it turned out to be not that easy, but it seems to be done now! See my updated answer

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is necessary.  I have a similar application, and have discovered that FileName = "powershell" works on some machines but not others.